# AutoPostBack only works when Chrome's Javascript Console is open

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, console

I have a checkbox that autopostbacks.  It works in IE and FF, but not in Chrome, so I tried opening Chrome's Javascript console to find the problem.  Here's where it gets really strange.

When the console is open, the autopostback works perfectly.
When I close it, nothing happens.

I've tried doing it in the same sequence, or multiple times in a row, but the only variable that makes a difference seems to be the javascript console.

Answer (score 0):

Hard to answer without seeing any code, but it could be that your code calls some console functions (`console.log`, `console.warn`, etc), and that some of those, for some reason, fails when the console is not available.

Answer (score 0):

I experienced a similar problem with a project recently. It turned out to be a problem with hooking to the window object via jQuery for events such as scrolling; switched to using the document object and the problems vanished.

This could help someone in the future.